# How can I fix my cards to be responsive using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css

I am having some issues to make bootstrap cards responsive to the width range of 460px to 700px. I would like to make them one under another using bootstrap command col-12 or col-sm-12 but they are not working.

```html
<!--FEATURE-->
        <div id="features" class="container-fluid features-container">
            <h1 class="features">Features</h1>
            <div class="card-deck">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="assets/images/user-images/gym-girl.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="gym-girl">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">CARDIO</h5>
                        <p><strong class="price">$49.99</strong>/Month</p>
                        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, regione viderer mel an, ex usu utinam prompta erroribus, ut fugit graeco regione qui. Et habemus dissentias sit, ea duis quidam sea, agam quando sit at.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="assets/images/user-images/gym-guy.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="gym-guy">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">STRENGTH</h5>
                        <p><strong class="price">$24.99</strong>/Month</p>
                        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, regione viderer mel an, ex usu utinam prompta erroribus, ut fugit graeco regione qui. Et habemus dissentias sit, ea duis quidam sea, agam quando sit at..</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="assets/images/user-images/gym-team.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="gym-team">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">PILATES</h5>
                        <p><strong class="price">$39.99</strong>/Month</p>
                        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, regione viderer mel an, ex usu utinam prompta erroribus, ut fugit graeco regione qui. Et habemus dissentias sit, ea duis quidam sea, agam quando sit at..</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the card class has some properties that may be interfering with the normal column break points. I've placed each card element within a div that contains the column classes, and I added the row class to the card-deck element. The snippet shows the row has 3 columns and then breaks to 1 column when smaller than 768px, which is the medium break point:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div id="features" class="container-fluid features-container">
  <h1 class="features">Features</h1>
  <div class="card-deck row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="assets/images/user-images/gym-girl.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="gym-girl">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">CARDIO</h5>
          <p><strong class="price">$49.99</strong>/Month</p>
          <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, regione viderer mel an, ex usu utinam prompta erroribus, ut fugit graeco regione qui. Et habemus dissentias sit, ea duis quidam sea, agam quando sit at.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="assets/images/user-images/gym-guy.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="gym-guy">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">STRENGTH</h5>
          <p><strong class="price">$24.99</strong>/Month</p>
          <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, regione viderer mel an, ex usu utinam prompta erroribus, ut fugit graeco regione qui. Et habemus dissentias sit, ea duis quidam sea, agam quando sit at..</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="assets/images/user-images/gym-team.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="gym-team">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">PILATES</h5>
          <p><strong class="price">$39.99</strong>/Month</p>
          <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, regione viderer mel an, ex usu utinam prompta erroribus, ut fugit graeco regione qui. Et habemus dissentias sit, ea duis quidam sea, agam quando sit at..</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: thank you very much. I was doing almost the same as you. However, I was setting the cols to the same place as the .card classes instead of wrapping and place them with another div.  Cheers.